# See (list) files changed between local and remote branch - git

Tags: git, git-diff

How do I list files that are "diff"ed between my current local and the corresponding remote branch?

The situation is that I had made a push to remote earlier and since then have rebased off master + squashed some commits.

On doing a git status, I get

> Your branch and 'origin/YourBranch' have diverged, and have 11 and 2
>   different commits each, respectively.

I do not want to do a "`git diff origin/YourBranch YourBranch`" because the number of changes made is large. After confirming that the files which have changed between local and remote makes sense, I shall do a force push.

Comment: Try `git diff --name-only commit1 commit2`

Comment: I was of the opinion that since I am comparing a file between two branches (remote and local), it would not be considered as commits, but as branches. However, I was able to look at the hash of the latest commit on remote and pass that instead of commit1. By doing a git log, I found the hash of the local branch's latest commit, which represented commit2. So this did work.

Comment: Git will handle any valid SHA1 reference (commit hash) or pointer to it (branch/tag).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To list just file names, use the [`name-only`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---name-only) flag like this:

```
git diff --name-only origin/YourBranch YourBranch
```

`name-only` will (from the [Git doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---name-only)):

> Show only names of changed files

BTW, this can also be used for other commands, such as [`show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#git-show---name-only).

Comment: `--name-status` and `--stat` are similar to `--name-only` but give a bit more info about each file (just FYI).